# Silex, die(), and weird caching

Tags: php, silex

I have a given `get` function in Silex API that is running on a dev server (its not running locally).

I wanted to print debug only a part of the payload, so I did a `print_r($part_of_payload)` and I didn't want to see anything else so I called `die()`. That worked.

I took out the `die()` function and now it seems that Silex cached that response somewhere. Other endpoints weren't affected. I removed the file completely and I'm *still* getting the response from before removing the `die()` function, even though the entire endpoint no longer exists.

How do I fix this caching issue?

Edit: Adding the file back, the endpoint works for any other id I give it other than the original one I used.

I tried multiple browsers and computers.

Comment: Silex does not this kind of caching by itself (specially because Twig is not involved), so no caching on the Silex side. May be there is an HTTP reverse cache (like varnish?) somewhere? Another possibility (remote but still...)  is that you updated another server?

Comment: The same thing is now happening when i just do a normal print_r() without the die(). 
I don't think we have anything setup like varnish.

Comment: Can you create a PHP file on the public web folder and do a ```print_r("Hello")``` then check on browser. After that, change the ```print_r("Hello")``` for another string and see what happens...